# Silverlight HyperlinkButton only content clickable

Tags: silverlight

I have a HyperlinkButton on my page, the content is just plain text.
But, as you can see in the picture below, the HyperlinkButton is often wider than the actual content.
This may be confusing since people only expect something to happen when actually clicking on the link.

How do I make the HyperlinkButton as wide as the content, or only the content clickable ?
I have tried setting the style but that didn't help.

Thank you for any help.
Dominic Rooijackers

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC56092.png

Comment: Multiple ways, `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`, `Width="Auto"`, or there's lots of others, if you want to do it at the template level, all you need to change is add `<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow..!!

For your question, I would say you are on right track of using style for this. What you have to do is just remove visual states from default style of hyperlink and also remove unnecessary elements of hyperlink. You can all do this in minutes using Expression Blend. For now I am making your life a bit easier. You can use following style of hyperlink to go ahead.

```
   <Style x:Key="ContentPresenterStyle1" TargetType="ContentPresenter"/>
        <Style x:Key="HyperlinkButtonStyle1" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF73A9D8"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                                <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
                            </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Style="{StaticResource ContentPresenterStyle1}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Have a happy learning..!! :)